# GWT Randomly generated data area spread

Tags: java, gwt

I am trying to generate random data for (x,y) points data set. However, this generated data is evenly spread out over area plot. My question is this: How could I generate this data so that it would not be evenly spread. Example:. some points close to each other, some far. In other words, they would not make a nice square as they do now.

Code generating this data is fairly simply:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Random;

int max = Random.nextInt(4000);
int howManyMarkers = 8600;

for (int k = 0; k < howManyMarkers; k++) {

    double x = Random.nextDouble() * max;
    double y = Random.nextDouble() * max;

    //(x,Y) makes one point (of any color) that you can see in the pictures I attached
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Expected result:** red lines should make it clear what I mean (crossed out data in this example should not be there).

[image]

**Note** that [gwt](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Random.html) classes were used, not java.util. to generate this data. I would prefer to rely on gwt if possible, since my project that is related to all this is built using GWT/P. I could do it using java.util.Random but I would rather not.

**Another note** 
I only need data sets like these to simulate huge data sets in my tests, so I could do performance tests for gwt + secha gxt for Scatter/trend line charts. I suppose it does not really matter what classes are used as long as its java. These data sets that I have so far are not realistic, since real data distribution is not like that (I guess that would make sense since real data is not random...). Example of a perfect data set incoming.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want? Uniform distribution means that an item has as much of a chance as falling anywhere as anywhere else. Gaussian distribution (as in the answer from @Zionsof), on the other hand, means that it is more likely to fall toward the middle of the range than the edges. A role of a die is uniform, but a random person's height tends to be gaussian. How do you define the area above and below that red line?

Comment: @ColinAlworth I thought I was fairly specific :) the red line in theory could be anywhere, it just shows that points are not scattered evenly over the plot. I will post you another example, which is exactly what I want.

Comment: It is clear from your post that it may be arbitrary, but not how you want to define/provide it to the code, since your example seems to be missing it. Random number distributions, being random, don't always conform to our expectations. The kind of "clustering" you are asking for isn't something that random numbers do, in most of the typical distributions that are used. You can actually see some clustering in your example - groups of dots that touch, and then spaces between those groups.

Comment: Also, GWT vs Java vs any other language like R or python: this is how random numbers work in general, the concept won't be specific to the browser or how GWT emulates Java.

Comment: @ColinAlworth My pointing out GWT vs JAVA meant that GWT classes have no gaussian implemented, and such other implementations that you would expect from java might be missing from GWT. Ofcourse it is possible to write your own classes but I don't want to overcomplicate this.

Comment: @ColinAlworth as for the missing definition of code that would do number distribution that I want, well I am not quite sure how to do that hence posting here...I needed ideas about algorithm for this distribution before writing code that would do it. But it is becoming clear to me that this will not be done easily.

Comment: I would appreciate if 4 more people voted to close this. Since it's become too broad of a question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as your number of markers is quite big, it makes sense that it would be generated as such evenly, since your method is generating uniformly distributed numbers. See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble()).

Maybe you should try to use not uniformly, but maybe `Random.nextGaussian()` which will give a normal distribution instead of uniform.

Comment: Gaussian is better, but still not quite what I am looking. Since it also retains same pattern every iteration, only not a square now, but a rough circle. I wonder if it would be possible to get a randomly distributed points.

Comment: Well, think about it. Those ARE randomly distributed points. Except, since you have many of them, it converges to some form, even when it is randomized. This is exactly the central limit theorem, as you can recall.

REALLY random numbers are impossible to generate. There is no real random in our life. What you could possible do, if you like, is simply generate a new max every time instead of generating one at first, and then using random using this new max. Then it would not be of the same form each time